# Why are patch antennas used instead of planar dipole antennas?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, wireless, radiation, dipole

As far as I know, the major advantage of patch antenna over dipole antenna is its directivity. If the planar dipole antenna can achieve the same directivity then why do we use patch antennas? Are there any other advantages of patch antennas over dipoles apart from directivity and ease of fabrication?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other advantages of patch antennas over dipoles apart from directivity and ease of fabrication?

Smaller size *(can be even smaller by [using high-permittivity dielectrics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623328/how-does-selecting-a-higher-permittivity-substrate-in-patch-antenna-reduce-its-s/623332#623332))*, higher gain *(due to hemispherical radiation)*, and narrower bandwidth *(if really needed)* are other advantages.

Comment: Patch antennae are also circularly polarized, so they don’t suffer from fading due to misalignment like dipoles.

Comment: By using high permittivity dielectric the size of planar dipole can be reduced as well. And how is the gain higher than patch?

Comment: @MrunalShinde using high permittivity dielectrics the size can be reduced, yes; but the gain will be lower as well *(due to the lower E-field radiation)*. As for the gain difference between dipoles and patch (or microstrip in general), dipoles radiate spherical into space but the patch radiate hemi-spherical (think of this like power density) so about twice radiation i.e. 3dB in ideal conditions.

Comment: So the gain of patch will be higher right? As the radiation is more concentrated in one direction.

Comment: @MrunalShinde true.

Comment: So if we use dipole antenna with a reflector(i.e. Planar dipole antenna) then spherical radiation pattern can be converted to hemi spherical and can be increased i.e. the gain of planar dipole antenna and patch is almost same. So why don't we use planar dipole instead of patch?

Comment: @MrunalShinde that's true. `So why don't we use planar dipole instead of patch?` and that's a very good question. I really don't know, tbh. Maybe there are some disadvantages that needs to be resolved by research and study. Maybe it's about feeding as it's easier for a patch (line feed). And also the bandwidth can be easily modified on a patch by simple geometric manipulations.